# How do you login to docker hub when using containerd?

Tags: docker, containerd

With docker I would run `docker login`, but how do you do similar with `ctr`/`containerd`?

We need to login due to hitting rate limits:

> ctr: failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code [https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/[...]](https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/%5B...%5D): 429 Too Many Requests - Server message: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit

Following [the containerd docs](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/registry.md#configure-registry-credentials) with `/etc/containerd/config.toml`:

```
version = 2
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."docker.io".auth]
  username = "myusername"
  password = "mypassword"
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also the version from https://github.com/containerd/cri/issues/835#issuecomment-403652902 but with `docker.io` instead also fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, me too and I don't understand why. So, I edited my config like as guide: https://docs.d2iq.com/dkp/kommander/1.4/operations/manage-docker-hub-rate-limits/

Like as you can see, original code in document

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."docker.io".auth]
```

If change to this (full domain), it works

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry-1.docker.io".auth]
```

Restart containerd and check.

Testing, write bash script

```
TOKEN=$(curl --user 'YOUR_LOGIN_USER:YOUR_LOGIN_PASSWORD' "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:ratelimitpreview/test:pull" | jq -r .token)
curl --head -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ratelimitpreview/test/manifests/latest | grep -i rate
```

My result, avaiable 198/200

```
ratelimit-limit: 200;w=21600
ratelimit-remaining: 198;w=21600
```